# When to update local react state based on data from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, architecture, react-redux

Lets say my use-case is to print a list of posts. I have the following react component.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: !!(props.posts && props.posts.length)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.loaded ? null : this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.loaded
                    ? this.props.posts.length
                        ? this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
                                return <li key={index}>{post.title}</li>;
                          })
                        : 'No posts'
                    : 'Loading'}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

`fetchPosts` is an action which makes an API call to fetch posts from DB and then updates the redux store with data. Now, my questions are

1. When should I update my local React state as per the props?

Initially, `this.props.posts` would either be `undefined` or `[]` so `this.state.loaded` would be `false` and we will make an API call to fetch. Once, the data is fetched then should I update it as

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        loaded: nextProps.posts && nextProps.posts.length
    });
}
```

This sets the local state and initially `spinner/loader` will be shown and then `posts` or `no posts`. However, as far as I understand, React documentation discourages to `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps` as that `lifecycle` hook will be called many times in React 16 and is also deprecated.

**So, in which lifecycle hook should I update local state?**

2. Would it be better to maintain the loading mechanism in Redux only?

   ```
   class App extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
       }

       compomentDidMount() {
           this.props.loaded ? null : this.props.fetchPosts();
       }

       render() {
           return (
               <ul>
                   {this.props.loaded
                       ? this.props.posts.length
                           ? this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
                                   return <li key={index}>{post.title}</li>;
                           })
                           : 'No posts'
                       : 'Loading'}
               </ul>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Here everything is maintained in Redux store only. If any other approach would be better then I would love to know. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you simply check the `posts` in your `render` method without keeping an internal `loaded` state?

Comment: @devserkan You mean to check if `posts` exists and if there is any `posts` length?

Comment: Yes. Actually you are doing a similar thing in your second example but what is `loaded` prop there?

Comment: Yes, it seems you can just check the status of the posts prop instead. There's not much point in adding an additional layer of state, as the canonical source of truth is the posts prop. Generally, the more state there is, the more complex things get.

Comment: @devserkan @adam-thomas I can check the props as in if `props.posts && props.posts.length` then show `posts` else `loading`. However, there might be the case when there are no `posts` are found? (Empty API response)

Comment: But this condition handles the situation you describe? Does not it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended solution would be to move that to `mapStateToProps`. Most of the time when you need data from your store (here it's `posts`) or data that is derived from store (here `loading`) then `mapStateToProps` is the correct place to  inject that. It is usually a good idea to keep the component as dumb as possible that takes data from the store. Also it it kind of violating the single source of truth principle to keep state in a component that is derived from the store because it can get out of sync if you do not pay attention:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {loading, posts} = this.props;

        if (loading) return 'Loading';

        if (!posts.length) return 'No Posts';

        return (
            <ul>
                {posts.map((post, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{post.title}</li>;
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({posts}) => ({
    posts
    loading: !posts,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, /* mapDispatchToProps */)(App);
```

Comment: I liked this approach. Just `loading` -> `loaded`. Typo I thinkç

Comment: @devserkan Ah I see. Sorry, you are totally correct. Updated.

Comment: @trixn So, just to confirm, `posts` initially would be `empty array`. Hence, on mount, `loading` will be `true` and we `dispatch` an action to `fetch` and render aptly. Once data is fetched, if `empty response` then `posts` would stay as `empty array` else `array with data` and `loading` will be still be `true` only.

Comment: @trixin If we take `posts` as `undefined` / 'null` initially then `loading` will be `false`. So. no loading UI would be shown.

Comment: @Yomesh Initially it should be `null` or `undefined`. This is when `loading` is `true`. Then after the data where fetched `posts` is either an empty array or a populated array.

Comment: @trixn oh you just updated your answer with single negate!

Comment: @Yomesh Yes you are right I had a typo there from editing my answer. Now it is correct. It has to be `loading: !posts`.

Comment: @Yomesh Just as a note. An empty array still evaluates to `true`. So even if `posts` is empty `loading` will be `false`. This is when you it renders `No Posts`.

Comment: @Yomesh Yes it was just for clearity. The main point of my answer is that data that is derived from the store should be calculated in `mapStateToProps`. This will solve your problem because then your component does not need to have a state at all.

Comment: @trixn Yes. Got it. Much appreciated. Answer marked!

Answer (score 3):

2 is correct. It is better to maintain the state in Redux only. Otherwise, you have two separate states for this component!